# Java Jersey: Need to Produce imageurl instead of image

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

I am Running my server on localhost:8080. I want to produce a list of Restaurants with restaurantImage associated with it. I am uploading the image with its Id, in my localdrive. My upload status is:

```
{
  "uploadstatus": "C:/data/5731453cf1a60921d4d1b8b8oracle.JPG"
}
```

when I am getting this as a list i found these from my controller.

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "5731453cf1a60921d4d1b8b8",
      "name": "Kualalam",
      "address": "kkkk",
      "restaurantImage": "C:/data/5731453cf1a60921d4d1b8b8oracle.JPG",
      "review": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code I am using to get the response:

```
 @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response list() {

        Map<Object, Object> apiResponse     = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Map<Object, Object> serviceResponse = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        try {

            List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.list();

            serviceResponse.put("total", restaurants.size());
            serviceResponse.put("list", restaurants);

           return Response.ok(serviceResponse).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error("Error in getting restaurants list:", e);
            apiResponse.put("error", e.getMessage());
        }

        return Response.status(500).entity(apiResponse).build();
    }
```

what I am wanting here, I would like to get this restaurant image as **http://localhost:8080/data/5731453cf1a60921d4d1b8b8oracle.JPG** . How can you i configure my controller to achieve the desired output?

Comment: your Response seems to be type of `java.util.HashMap`, how do you expect to get a `Response` in the type of _URL_ (`java.net.URL`) ?

Comment: I am trying like this, now: 
List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.list();
            for(Restaurant restaurant: restaurants) {
                String imageURI = restaurant.getRestaurantImage();
                restaurant.setRestaurantImage(AppConstant.RESTAURANT_IMG_URL+imageURI);
            }

Comment: You try to get the path _AbsolutePath_ and set it into your servicResponse i guess. But single thread will not let you read the path and write to your map, you should try the observer pattern to get the absolute path and then write it to your _HashMap_.

Comment: Can you help me with some code snippet?

Comment: I don't have enough time to give a code snippet but i have a link

 (http://www.java2blog.com/2013/02/observer-design-pattern-in-java.html) which describes the situation efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retrieve your resource AbsolutePath you should use [UriInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)
which is the injectable interface that provides access to application and request URI information.

Your code could be something like this:

```
@GET    
@Produces("application/json")
public Response list(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    ...
    try {
        List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.list(); 
        for(Restaurant restaurant: restaurants) { 
            String imageURI = restaurant.getRestaurantImage();          
            String imageFileName = imageURI.substring(imageURI.lastIndexOf("/"));
            restaurant.setRestaurantImage(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+imageFileName); 
        }
        serviceResponse.put("total", restaurants.size());
        serviceResponse.put("list", restaurants);
        return Response.ok(serviceResponse).build();
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

Probably you'll need an image Provider (to get your 'http://localhost:8080/data/5731453cf1a60921d4d1b8b8oracle.JPG' image)

```
@GET
@Path("data/{imgFilename}") 
@Produces("image/png")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("imgFilename") String fileName) {
    File image = restaurantService.getImgByName(fileName);          
    return Response.ok(image).build();      
}
```

Every path has to be well designed to suit your application and resourse URIs.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: As I will integrate this api with mobile, I dont want api calls for every items in the list. So there should be no api for getting the image.

Comment: You can omit the second resource. The two @GET providers are disconnected as a direct dependence.